# A question about complex power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

My book says the following:

> Let $\sum_n a_nz^n$ be a convergent complex power series with radius of convergence $r$. Then there exist $C,A\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n|<CA^n$, where $A>1/r$.

I don't know how to prove this. I can think of an argument, but that would only be valid if the series were absolutely convergent, which is clearly not the case here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: A power series *is* absolutely convergent for $|z|<r$, being majorized by a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Let $r$ be the radius of convergence and let $0 < 1/A < r$. Because $\sum_{n}a_{n}A^{-n}$ converges, then $\lim_{n} a_{n}A^{-n}=0$. Every convergent sequence is bounded. Therefore $|a_{n}| \le MA^{n}$ for some constant $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exist no such $C$ then $$\mid a_n\mid >A^n$$for infinitely many n.Hence the series contains infinitely many terms with modulus greater than $1$ for $z$ sufficiently close to $r$ which makes the series divergent.

Comment: I can't follow your proof by contradiction. First, "suppose there exist no such C **and A**"... and then, $|a_n| \geq CA^n$ for at least one $n$. You should go looking for conditions where you create an infinite sequence of such $|a_n|$...

Comment: @Igor have you noticed for infinitely many n part?

Comment: @Igor the answer abovein fact proves the stronger statement which is valid for every A>1/r..